# Are there any portable versions of Git for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, git, portable-executable, portable-applications

I'd like to be able to do some development work on public/borrowed computers (where I have no root privileges) and I've managed to get most of my tools working off of a USB stick but I still haven't found a Git solution.

The portable versions of Git that I have found are Windows-only. Do you know of any Mac alternatives?

**EDIT:** I've gotten a few suggestions to just copy my current installation of git from /usr/bin and put that on a USB drive. That's a great idea but I don't have a current installation of git to copy from. I won't have my own computer back for a couple of weeks.

Would you happen to know where I could grab a pre-compiled version of git for OSX? I don't have access to homebrew or... anything really. Ideally I could just grab a zip file from somewhere and dump it on my USB stick.

Comment: Why can't you just copy it from `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892695/can-i-use-git-without-installing ?

Comment: @CarlNorum I don't have anywhere to copy it from since I don't have a home computer at the moment. Where can I get it?

Comment: @Duotrigesimal The answers to that question involve compiling from source, which I can't do at the moment (I do JS development so I don't have C dev tools), or using JGit, doesn't have as many commands/options.

Comment: Have your tried mounting the usb stick and trying export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/git/on/usb/stick? Might work and allow you to access git properly.

Comment: @bms The problem is that I don't have the /path/to/git/ part. :/ The OSX download that they have on http://git-scm.com/ is an installer and I can't run it with out admin privileges.

Comment: @jen-montes You could try [a pure python install of mercurial](http://vilimpoc.org/blog/2010/10/04/installing-mercurial-without-admin-rights-and-no-c-compiler/) and then try adding the [hg-git plugin](http://hg-git.github.com/).

Comment: Perhaps some kind soul (not me, I don't have a Mac) can copy their own installed git files to a server somewhere.

Comment: @bms While technically not in the scope of the question (I prefer git), I still gave your suggestion a shot. Sadly, the pure python install instructions require that I `make` the Mercurial installation, but I don't have that command available.

Comment: @KeithThompson I hacked a Google search together to try to find it somewhere: `-inurl:(htm|html|php) intitle:"index of" "last modified" "parent directory" description size  "usr/bin" hdiutil git`. I included `hdiutil` because I think it's unique to Macs and it would also live in `/usr/bin`, but no results.

Comment: Not surprising; there's no particular reason for someone to copy their Git executables to a server (outside your specific unusual circumstances). My suggestion was that somebody reading these comments might be willing to do it for you. (I'd do it myself if I had a Mac.)

Comment: Everyone should have `make` available. That is not a valid excuse.

Comment: @KeithThompson, people don't usually know, that's the point of that Google Search. Works more for windows than for Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to put together a solution based on ideas from several different people (thanks to all of you):

- Download the Git binary for Mac OSX from [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/). The downloaded DMG contains a PKG file.
- Unpack the PKG file with [unpkg](http://www.timdoug.com/unpkg/) or something similar. (This step is necessary because normally PKG files can only be installed with root privileges.)
- Drop the `etc` and `git` folders that were just unpacked onto your USB stick.

Now, whenever you plug in your USB stick, just make sure to put the location of the `git` directory on your `PATH` (like this: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/git/on/usb/stick`) and you'll be good to go!

**NOTE:** I've tested many of the `git` commands using this method and most seem to work without any issues. However, `git init` will complain like this: `warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates`. Not surprising since the templates are actually on your USB stick and not `/usr/local`. Despite this warning my repos seem to be working just fine.

Comment: The warning can be avoided if you set `GIT_EXEC_PATH`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787385/#answer-15790100 for details.

Comment: @Jen, [https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Git-shouldnt-you-do-export-PATH-foo-PATH-instead-of-export-PATH-PATH-foo](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Git-shouldnt-you-do-export-PATH-foo-PATH-instead-of-export-PATH-PATH-foo)

Answer (score 3):

Add a environmental variable GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR
to quote the documentation

> The template directory contains files and directories that will be
>   copied to the $GIT_DIR after it is created.
>
> The template directory will be one of the following (in order):
>
> the argument given with the --template option;
>
> the contents of the $GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR environment variable;
>
> the init.templatedir configuration variable; or
>
> the default template directory: /usr/share/git-core/templates.

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded my `/usr/bin/git` and `/usr/bin/git-shell` to

- http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/~ajo/disseminate/git
- http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/~ajo/disseminate/git-shell

You can try those, but I have no idea if this approach is likely to work. (There are no interesting shared-library dependencies reported by `otool -L`, but I don't know what else might theoretically go wrong with the idea.)

FWIW, I use Mac OS X 10.8.2 and `git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)`.

Not sure if this is appropriate as an "answer", since I don't plan to leave those links working indefinitely. Maybe I (or someone) can delete this answer in a month or two.

Comment: you can create public gists for those, although it isn't clear how much of that is specific to Mountain Lion

Comment: Hey! Thanks for doing this! Definitely helpful for the short-term, but you're right: it's not really an appropriate answer. You still get karma points though.

Comment: @JenMontes Did you try putting these exact binaries on a USB stick and did it actually work for you? or did you run into any of those "unknown unknowns"? — I did see your final answer, which involved git binaries (from a more trusted source :)), so I guess the approach does work.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Your `git` binary did work very well, though I would get the same templates warning when I tried `git init`. I don't really use `git-shell` much, but I made a `git-shell-commands` folder in my home directory and it seemed to work like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's command line tools for developers include git, I believe. You can find them on http://developer.apple.com/; you might need a free developer account. They package will want to install to `/usr/bin` etc., but you should be able to use `pax` to extract the contents wherever you want.