# OS X: portable Git (aka install multiple Git versions)

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion

I'm currently trying to install multiple Git versions on OS X for testing purposes. After downloading the OS X installer bundle from [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/downloads) (which installs to `/usr/local/git`), I move it to a different location, e.g. `~/git-1.7.11.1` or `~/git-1.8.1`. Unfortunately, Git does not like this move:

```
$ ~/git-1.7.11.1/bin/git fetch
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

or even worse:

```
$ ~/git-1.7.11.1/bin/git pull
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        shell
```

When I set the path, it also does not work:

```
$ export PATH=~/git-1.7.11.1/bin:$PATH
$ which git
/Users/xxx/git-1.7.11.1/bin/git
$ git pull
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        shell
```

Is there anything I need to change in the Git bundles, too, to make them portable (aka running at each location)?

Comment: You could probably install multiple `git` versions from source, with the `--prefix=/path/to/install/dir`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892695/can-i-use-git-without-installing). If you've installed to `/usr/bin/local`, then moved the installed files, you should check that `~/git-1.7.11.1/bin` is in your `$PATH` so that `git` can find the various `git` binary files.

Comment: I want to create *portable* Git installations which are not bound to a certain location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The git-scm installer does appear to install everything in /usr/local/git (inferred by looking at the uninstall.sh file in the git-scm download).  Therefore, renaming the git directory should not be a problem.  What you need to do is augment your path as such:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git-1.7.11.1/bin
```

so that `git` and all its helper programs can be found.

Note that this approach won't work if you try to call multiple git versions from the same shell; all the versions will get their helper programs from the first directory in PATH.

[edit] You will also need to set the environment variable GIT_EXEC_PATH.  Use

```
git --exec-path
```

to learn what it currently is and then use a new one with:

> git --exec-path=<...git-1.7.11.1/...>

or by defining GIT_EXEC_PATH.

Also it appears that the build path is built into the `git` executable which may indicate that `git` expects its supporting files in a default location.

```
ebg@ebg(147)$ strings git | grep usr
/usr/local/git
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

ebg@ebg(148)$ strings /usr/bin/git | grep usr
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

So, use GIT_EXEC_PATH. See the [GIT Man Page](http://bit.ly/Z8Eyoy) for more info.

Comment: If you build from source, you can also run without installing or setting GIT_EXEC_PATH by calling bin-wrappers/git as described in [INSTALL](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.1/INSTALL#L41-L45). – Glen K

Answer (score 2):

I needed to set `GIT_EXEC_PATH`:

```
$ ~/git-1.7.11.1/bin/git pull
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        shell
$ export GIT_EXEC_PATH=~/git-1.7.11.1/libexec/git-core/
$ ~/git-1.7.11.1/bin/git pull
Password for 'https://xxx':
```